# I cant add buttons to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = "1";
    this.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Child page starts like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server"/>
```

MasterPage

```
    <div align="center" runat="server" >
         <form id="form1" runat="server">
               <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
         </form>
    </div>
```

As shown here, the button controls are inside

So why do i get this:

http://localhost:2427/WebSite10/AllQuestions.aspx

```
Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Post an image, or the exception message. No one but you can access your `localhost`.

Comment: Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: How about using `placeholder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something on these lines should work,this will help in rendering the control

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Click Me";
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
b.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Write(hw.InnerWriter);
```

Or you could also do it via a `PlaceHolder`

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="holder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Click Me";
holder1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: Awesome..man..what is that place holder?...can i put that placeholder into a table..?

Answer (score -1):

Try to qdd it to the contentplaceholder instead of the page itself

Comment: why would you downvote then, it is still the solution, and why wouldn't you know how then, it works the same as to a form/webpage